# extract data from html code

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I want to extract data into div tags using BeautifulSoup :

```
<div class="post contentTemplate" itemprop="text">Data to extract<div class="clear"></div></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

data = '<div class="post contentTemplate" itemprop="text">Data to extract<div class="clear"></div></div>'
soup = bs(data)
m = soup.findAll("div", {"class": "post contentTemplate"})
for k in m:
    print(k.get_text())
```

Output:

```
Data to extract
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the `get_text()` method. this will extract all text from every `div` that `find_all()` finds in the source code.

```
data = [e.get_text() for e in html.find_all('div')]
```

when run it returns:

```
[u'Data to extract', u'']
```

if you don't want the empty values just filter them out.

```
data = [e.get_text() for e in html.find_all('div') if e.get_text()]
```